# Values are not getting updated in the DB

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have registration form and i am inserting mandatory fields at first page after that based on userid i am updating some details in the second page below is my code

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Insertreg]

( @id int output,@FirstName varchar (50),@LastName varchar(50) ,@Dob datetime,
        @Gender varchar(20) ,@MobileNo nchar(10) ,@Country varchar(50) ,
    @State varchar (50),@EmailId varchar (50),@Password nchar (15)

)
as
begin
insert into Profile_Master(FirstName,LastName,Dob,Gender,MobileNo,Country,State,EmailId,Password)
 values
(@FirstName,@LastName,@Dob,@Gender,@MobileNo,@Country,@State,@EmailId,@Password)
set @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
end


    ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_update]

(@id int output,@FormFiledBy varchar (50),@MaritalStatus varchar (50),@Height varchar (50),
@Religion varchar (50),@Caste varchar (100),
 @MotherTongue varchar(50),@Education varchar (100),@Occupation varchar(50),
 @CountryofResidence varchar (50),@EducationDetails varchar (100),@AnnualIncome varchar(50),
@CountryOfBirth varchar(50),@BirthPlace varchar(50),@TimeOfBirth nchar(10),@StarSign varchar (100),
@Gothram varchar (50),@Rassi varchar(50),@HavinChildren varchar(10),@PhysicalStatus varchar (100))

as
begin

update Profile_Master
 set FormFiledBy=@FormFiledBy,MaritalStatus=@MaritalStatus,Height=@Height,
Religion=@Religion,Caste=@Caste,MotherTongue=@MotherTongue,
Education=@Education,Occupation=@Occupation,CountryofResidence=@CountryofResidence,EducationDetails=@EducationDetails,
AnnualIncome=@AnnualIncome,CountryOfBirth=@CountryOfBirth,BirthPlace=@BirthPlace,TimeOfBirth=@TimeOfBirth,
StarSign=@StarSign,Gothram=@Gothram,Rassi=@Rassi,HavinChildren=@HavinChildren,PhysicalStatus=@PhysicalStatus

where UserId=@id
end

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get User ID from DAL
        int chk = 0;
        if (Session["EmailID"] != null)
        {
            emailID = Session["EmailID"].ToString();
        }
        ProfileMasterBLL prfbll =new ProfileMasterBLL();
        prfbll.EmailID = emailID;
        string userid = ProfileMasterDAL.GetUserIdByEmailID(emailID);

        // Capture remaining parameters
        if (userid != null)
        {

            prfbll.FormFiledBy = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text;
            prfbll.MaritalStatus = RadioButtonList2.SelectedItem.Text;
            prfbll.Height = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
            prfbll.PhysicalStatus = RadioButtonList4.SelectedItem.Text;
            prfbll.Religion = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;
            prfbll.Caste = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text;
            prfbll.MotherTongue = DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text;
            prfbll.Education = DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text;
            prfbll.Occupation = DropDownList6.SelectedItem.Text;
            prfbll.CountryofResidence = DropDownList8.SelectedItem.Text;
            prfbll.EducationDetails = TextBox3.Text;
            prfbll.AnnualIncome = DropDownList7.SelectedItem.Text;
            prfbll.CountryOfBirth = DropDownList9.SelectedItem.Text;
            prfbll.BirthPlace = TextBox6.Text;
            prfbll.TimeOfBirth = TextBox7.Text;
            prfbll.StarSign = DropDownList10.SelectedItem.Text;
            prfbll.Gothram = TextBox8.Text;
            prfbll.Rassi = DropDownList12.Text;

            if (RadioButtonList2.SelectedItem.Text != "Single")
            {
                prfbll.HavinChildren = RadioButtonList7.SelectedItem.Text;
            }
            else
                {
                    RadioButtonList7.SelectedItem.Text = null;
                }
            }


            try
            {
                chk = ProfileMasterDAL.update(prfbll);
                if (chk >= 0)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('details updated');</script>");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }


public static int update(ProfileMasterBLL profileMasterBLL)
    {
        SqlParameter uid;
        SqlConnection conn = Generic.DBConnection.OpenConnection();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("sp_update", conn);
            cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormFiledBy", profileMasterBLL.FormFiledBy);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaritalStatus", profileMasterBLL.MaritalStatus);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", profileMasterBLL.Height);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Religion", profileMasterBLL.Religion);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Caste", profileMasterBLL.Caste);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Education", profileMasterBLL.Education);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", profileMasterBLL.Occupation);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryofResidence", profileMasterBLL.CountryofResidence);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EducationDetails", profileMasterBLL.EducationDetails);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryOfBirth", profileMasterBLL.CountryOfBirth);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthPlace", profileMasterBLL.BirthPlace);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeOfBirth", profileMasterBLL.TimeOfBirth);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StarSign", profileMasterBLL.StarSign);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gothram", profileMasterBLL.Gothram);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rassi", profileMasterBLL.Rassi);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HavinChildren", profileMasterBLL.HavinChildren);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhysicalStatus", profileMasterBLL.PhysicalStatus);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MotherTongue", profileMasterBLL.MotherTongue);
            cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AnnualIncome", profileMasterBLL.AnnualIncome);
            uid = cmdd.Parameters.Add("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            uid.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            return cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

but the problem is values are not getting updated in the DB can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
public static int Insert(ProfileMasterBLL profileMasterBLL)
    {
        // bool flag = false;
        SqlParameter pid;
        SqlConnection con = Generic.DBConnection.OpenConnection();

        try
        {

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insertreg", con);
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", profileMasterBLL.FirstName);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", profileMasterBLL.LastName);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dob", profileMasterBLL.Dob);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", profileMasterBLL.Gender);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNo", profileMasterBLL.MobileNo);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", profileMasterBLL.Country);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", profileMasterBLL.State);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", profileMasterBLL.EmailID);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", profileMasterBLL.Password);
           pid = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            pid.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            return cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: It throws no error but the values are not getting updated in the DB.

Comment: Use sql profiler and check  the query

Comment: I dont have sql profiler installed in my system....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update procedure is expecting to update

```
where UserId=@id
```

but you are not passing in an id.

If this class

```
ProfileMasterBLL
```

has a user id, you could assign it when you update the rest of the fields

```
  if (userid != null)
        {
            prfbll.UserId = userid; //Or whatever it's called
            prfbll.FormFiledBy = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text;
```

if not you need to update the signature

```
public static int update(ProfileMasterBLL profileMasterBLL, string userId)
```

and then pass the user id in also.

This would require changes to the parameters and to the stored procedure.

The SP shouldn't take an OUT param (and thus shouldn't be passed in that way.

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_update]

(@id int ,@FormFiledBy varchar (50),@MaritalStatus varchar (50),@Height varchar (50),
@Religion varchar (50),@Caste varchar (100),
 @MotherTongue varchar(50),@Education varchar (100),@Occupation varchar(50),
 @CountryofResidence varchar (50),@EducationDetails varchar (100),@AnnualIncome varchar(50),
@CountryOfBirth varchar(50),@BirthPlace varchar(50),@TimeOfBirth nchar(10),@StarSign varchar (100),
@Gothram varchar (50),@Rassi varchar(50),@HavinChildren varchar(10),@PhysicalStatus varchar (100))

as
begin

update Profile_Master
 set FormFiledBy=@FormFiledBy,MaritalStatus=@MaritalStatus,Height=@Height,
Religion=@Religion,Caste=@Caste,MotherTongue=@MotherTongue,
Education=@Education,Occupation=@Occupation,CountryofResidence=@CountryofResidence,EducationDetails=@EducationDetails,
AnnualIncome=@AnnualIncome,CountryOfBirth=@CountryOfBirth,BirthPlace=@BirthPlace,TimeOfBirth=@TimeOfBirth,
StarSign=@StarSign,Gothram=@Gothram,Rassi=@Rassi,HavinChildren=@HavinChildren,PhysicalStatus=@PhysicalStatus

where UserId=@id
end
```

and the parameter should be added

```
    SqlParameter uid;
    SqlConnection conn = Generic.DBConnection.OpenConnection();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("sp_update", conn);
        cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", userId ); //Or profileMasterBLL.UserId or whatever
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormFiledBy", profileMasterBLL.FormFiledBy);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaritalStatus", profileMasterBLL.MaritalStatus);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", profileMasterBLL.Height);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Religion", profileMasterBLL.Religion);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Caste", profileMasterBLL.Caste);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Education", profileMasterBLL.Education);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", profileMasterBLL.Occupation);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryofResidence", profileMasterBLL.CountryofResidence);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EducationDetails", profileMasterBLL.EducationDetails);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryOfBirth", profileMasterBLL.CountryOfBirth);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthPlace", profileMasterBLL.BirthPlace);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeOfBirth", profileMasterBLL.TimeOfBirth);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StarSign", profileMasterBLL.StarSign);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gothram", profileMasterBLL.Gothram);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rassi", profileMasterBLL.Rassi);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HavinChildren", profileMasterBLL.HavinChildren);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhysicalStatus", profileMasterBLL.PhysicalStatus);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MotherTongue", profileMasterBLL.MotherTongue);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AnnualIncome", profileMasterBLL.AnnualIncome);
```

Also remove these
            uid = cmdd.Parameters.Add("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            uid.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            return cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: userid is a identity column it is auto incremented.

Comment: I am calling the method in the first page of my UI

Comment: Does that code work properly and create the necessary records in the database?

Comment: It worked for sometime but after that again i am getting null value at             string userid = ProfileMasterDAL.GetUserIdByEmailID(profileMasterBLL.EmailID);

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the output argument from your update sp's @id parameter
2. set the value of @id in your c#'s update method